# After Formatting the x-Axis the initial and end values are not properly coming

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart

In the ganttchart x axis there are two rows.1st one represent month and 2nd one for days(1-15 & 15-30 range) of each month.After modifying the data as per above requirement, the 2nd row last month 2nd half dates are not displaying(e.g if the last month is December then in the 2nd row only 1-15 is coming)

```js
// THE CHART
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', 
{
     xAxis:  [
        //start date(1-15/16-30)
        {
          grid: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          className: 'dateRange-axis',
          style: {            
          },
          labels: {
            align: 'center',
            useHTML: true,
            style: {
            },
            formatter: function () {
              let lastDisplayDate;
              let date = new Date(this.value);
              let currentDate = moment(moment(date).valueOf()).utc().format("DD");
              const M = moment(moment(date).valueOf()).utc().format();
              let lastDate = moment(M).utc().daysInMonth();
              if (parseInt(currentDate) > 1 && parseInt(currentDate) < 15) {
                currentDate = '01';
              }
              if (parseInt(currentDate) > 16) {
                currentDate = 16;
              }
              if (parseInt(currentDate) != 1) {
                lastDisplayDate = lastDate
              } else {
                lastDisplayDate = parseInt(currentDate) + 14
              }

              let lable = currentDate + '-' + JSON.stringify(lastDisplayDate)
              return lable;
            }
          },          
          tickInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day
          tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
            var interval = this.options.tickInterval,
              ticks = [],
              count = 0;

            while (min < max) {
              let date = new Date(min);
              let currentDate_t = moment(moment(date).valueOf()).utc().format("DD");
              
              if (parseInt(currentDate_t) < 15 && count != 0) {
                const day_diff = parseInt(currentDate_t) - 1
                min = min - (this.options.tickInterval * day_diff)
              }

              date = new Date(min);
              const M = moment(moment(date).valueOf()).utc().format();
              let lastDate = moment(M).utc().daysInMonth();
              let currentDate = moment(moment(date).valueOf()).utc().format("DD");

              if (lastDate == 30 || parseInt(currentDate) == 1) {
                interval = this.options.tickInterval * 15;
              }
              if (lastDate == 31 && parseInt(currentDate) != 1) {
                interval = this.options.tickInterval * 16;
              }
              if ((lastDate == 28 || lastDate == 29) && parseInt(currentDate) != 1) {
                if (lastDate == 28)
                  interval = this.options.tickInterval * 13;
                if (lastDate == 29)
                  interval = this.options.tickInterval * 14;
              }
              ticks.push(min);
              min += interval;
              count++;
            }
            
            return ticks;
          }
        },
        {
          grid: {
            enabled: true                     
          },
          className: 'month-axis',
          tickColor: 'transparent',
          tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // months row
          labels: {
            align: 'center',
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            formatter: function () {
              let month = moment(moment(this.value)).utc().format("MMM");
              return month;
            }
          },
        }
      ],
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    visible: false,
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    data: [
   {
      name: 'project 1',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 1, 1),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
      assignee: 'Richards',
      y: 0
    }, {
      name: 'project 2',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 27),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 15),
      assignee: 'Richards',
      y: 1
    }, 
    {
      name: 'project 3',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 20),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 25),
      assignee: 'Richards',
      y: 2
    }, {
      name: 'project 4',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 30),
      assignee: 'Richards',
      y: 3
    }
    ],
    dataLabels: {  
   "align":"center",
   "format": "{point.name}",
   "padding":5,
     "font-size" : '7px',
    "font-weight" : 400,
   "verticalAlign":"bottom",

}
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you'll probably want to set `endOnTick` to `true` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.endOnTick)), since it is default `false`. Potentially also `startOnTick` to `true` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick)):

```
xAxis:  [{
        endOnTick: true,
        startOnTick: true,
        // ...
}]
```

Secondly, your `tickPositioner` does not generate a tick for this last position. It stops **before** the end of the last month, since it stops at the maximum value. Currently you have:

```
tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
    // ...
    while (min < max) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

A simple workaround to make it do one more round is this:

```
tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
    var last = false;
    // ...
    while (min < max || !last) {
        if(min >= max)
            last = true;
        // ...
    }
}
```

See this [JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/j09z35sq/) of it in action.